# Where to store token when the user doesn't want to be remembered

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage, access-token

We are using oAuth token authentication app (server is Webapi2 with Identity, client is angular.js).

On login - the server issues a token for the user to use on every request.
we store this token using local storage.

- The question is - how to store it on client if the user doesn't checks "Remember me" check box?

I looked at sessionStorage but there is no way to access it on other tab.
All I want is the client to forget the token when the browser window closes. how can I get this behavior - Do I have to use session Cookies for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Storing the token in a cookie is the right way to go. In case you also to have the case when the user can disable cookies appending the token to the URL for each request would be the way to go.